# How to set a variable in INSTALL4j during the installation to make it available in the .exe file after installation

Tags: java, installation, install4j

I made using `install4j` IDE. During the installation, I want to be able to assign a variable and make it available for the `.exe` file when the installation is complete.

Simplified scenario:

1. A user provides his name in the form while running the installer.
2. Installation process finished.
3. A user executes the created `.exe` file
4. Application Greets the user with: `Hello {name provided in step 1.}`

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [form components](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.helptopics.concepts.formScreens) that take user input, for example the "Text field" form component bind the input to an installer variable that is automatically registered as a [response file variable](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.helptopics.installers.responseFile).

For example, if the configured variable is "myName", then in your launcher you can retrieve the entered value via

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getInstallerVariable("myName")
```

For other installer variables that are not filled by form components, you can call

```
context.registerResponseFileVariable("otherVariable");
```

in a "Run script" action to make them available in the same way in your launchers.

Comment: Thanks, the last recommendation was exactly what I was looking for!